# Custom Push Segue removes navigation bar and tab bar in story board

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have the following defined in a custom Segue, let us call it SegueX:

```
@interface SegueX : UIStoryboardSegue
@end

@implementation SegueX

- (void)perform
{
    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];

    transition.duration = 0.3;
    transition.type = kCATransitionFade;

    [[self.sourceViewController navigationController].view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
    [[self.sourceViewController navigationController] pushViewController:[self destinationViewController] animated:NO];
}

@end
```

In my story board I have just changed a standard Push segue to SegueX. For some reason this will remove my navigation bar and tab bar. Furthermore all UIBarButtonItems I have defined in the story board after the custom segue are hidden at runtime. How do I fix this? I hope it is not meant to be this way...

Before changing to a custom segue

[image: Before changing to a custom segue]

After changing to a custom segue

[image: After changing to a custom segue]

[image]

Save this to Main.storyboard

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="4514" systemVersion="13A603" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" initialViewController="aUj-3O-DdX">
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="3747"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--Navigation Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="prC-ky-DMz">
            <objects>
                <navigationController definesPresentationContext="YES" id="aUj-3O-DdX" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <navigationBar key="navigationBar" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="2Uu-Rm-RXH">
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                    </navigationBar>
                    <toolbar key="toolbar" opaque="NO" clearsContextBeforeDrawing="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="aOK-Kc-Mfz">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="416" width="320" height="44"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                    </toolbar>
                    <connections>
                        <segue destination="PDT-yG-B9z" kind="relationship" relationship="rootViewController" id="w27-w2-lcd"/>
                    </connections>
                </navigationController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="fNx-r3-Dzg" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-65" y="-179"/>
        </scene>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="kMj-Al-ZjY">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="PDT-yG-B9z" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="RKt-BS-gn9"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="eFe-fv-bG6"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="JbT-x8-qhX">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="568"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="fTw-C6-P3N">
                                <rect key="frame" x="137" y="269" width="46" height="30"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                <state key="normal" title="Button">
                                    <color key="titleShadowColor" white="0.5" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                </state>
                                <connections>
                                    <segue destination="uMi-ds-4FY" kind="custom" id="mPL-yx-hFQ"/>
                                </connections>
                            </button>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    </view>
                    <navigationItem key="navigationItem" id="Im9-4G-4Ga"/>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="qXF-QN-k3Z" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="473" y="-177"/>
        </scene>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="ca6-vg-B3h">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="uMi-ds-4FY" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="jd0-A9-WOV"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="5VJ-sS-U1V"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="gJp-P2-rUC">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="568"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="pih-Kj-ioJ" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="1003" y="-179"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <simulatedMetricsContainer key="defaultSimulatedMetrics">
        <simulatedStatusBarMetrics key="statusBar"/>
        <simulatedOrientationMetrics key="orientation"/>
        <simulatedScreenMetrics key="destination" type="retina4"/>
    </simulatedMetricsContainer>
</document>
```

Comment: You'll be happy to know that it's not meant to be this way -- I copied your code, and it worked perfectly. Unfortunately, I have no idea why yours didn't work. What version of Xcode and iOS are you using (mine is Xcode 5.0.1 running iOS 7.0).

Comment: I am using Xcode 5.0 (5A1412), will try to upgrade and hopefully it will work!

Comment: Now I installed Xcode 5.0.2 but it did not help unfortunately, the same results still. Will update the question with info on the segue

Comment: Hmmm... that's curious. I assume that your source view controller is still embedded in the navigation controller? If you can post your project somewhere or email it to me, I'd be glad to take a look at it.

Comment: I will put the storyboard here, it seem to be a storyboard issue. As soon as I chose Style: "custom" in the Segue properties the navbar disappears

Comment: The nav bar and the tool bar should disappear in the storyboard when you change the segue -- that's normal. You can change the simulated metrics for the bottom bar to "Translucent Toolbar", which will add it back, so you can add buttons to it. But, you should still see both bars with their buttons at run time.

Comment: @rdelmar after trying to set the simulated metrics it totally makes sense. Please write this as the answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The navigation bar and the tool bar should disappear in the storyboard when you change the segue -- that's normal. You can change the simulated metrics for the bottom bar to "Translucent Toolbar", which will add it back, so you can add buttons to it (you only want to change the simulated metrics, not drag in another tool bar which would add a second tool bar). You should still see both bars with their buttons at run time.

Answer (score 11):

Try to check if you have set on storyboard an option like 
[image]
That metrics are inferred on the pushed view controller (but I'm pretty sure it doesn't count). 
[image]

And/or force the navigation bar and bottom bar to be visible programmatically using, inside the `-viewWillAppear` of the pushed view controller

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

Comment: No this is unfortunately not the case. "Hides bottom bar on push is unchecked. All in the second image is Inferred

Comment: Yes, everything works if I do it programatically. (Even the story board version works but the navigation item buttons does not get created in the app) So I actually have a navbar and a tabbar at runtime, but the buttons in the navbar are nonexistent, and there is no way for me to add buttons in the story board since the navbar is hidden here

Answer (score 0):

```
(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    ViewController * controller = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    controller.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=YES;
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Commentsegue"]) {
        //For hiding the tab bar 
        [segue.destinationViewController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
    } 
}
```