# Navigation bar works fine in iOS 8 but doesn't show up in iOS 7 (swift)

Tags: swift, ios7, ios8, uinavigationbar, compatibility

Pushing ViewController programmatically works fine in iOS 8 but in iOS 7 it neither shows navigation bar nor the bottom bar.

I tried:-  `self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)`

but it doesn't work.

My code for pushing view controller is

```
let viewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("info View") as infoViewController
viewController.isCompanyContact = true
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: Have you made any changes in Simulated Metrics (Property) of view controller in storyboard or XIB?

Comment: No i didn't do any changes in storyboard. it is set to inferred for top bar

Comment: Please check this link hope this is work for you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20066915/1616632

Comment: link you gave is not useful